# DIY Waterwheel which generates 100 W?

Tags: electrical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, power-electronics

I'm planning to build up a big [tipi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipi) with some friends for relaxing on nice summer evenings.  The tipi is going to be placed on the shore of a medium sized river, specifically the Wertach in Germany ([Wikipedia to Wertach (German)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wertach_%28Fluss%29)).
We also want some electricity there, to run a small Stereo and some light which together use about 100 W.  Therefore we thought about using a waterwheel.

Is it possible to build a waterwheel generator for about 400 EUR? And if it is, how could we do that? I already read that we could use a scooter engine for that.

Comment: The question is kinda broad and leaves a lot of work for us to do. I would say it's possible, as for the costs it depends on what you pay for the parts. Since you would buy them used there is not defnite price tag on the generator e.g.. You could check out [this site](http://www.builditsolar.com/Projects/Hydro/UnderShot/WaterWheel.htm) as a starting point and try to get more detailed with your question. Also please check if you are allowed to deploy the water wheel there. I'm not sure if there are any restrictions but I could image so, after all it's germany ;)

Comment: I'm putting your question on hold as too broad.  Open ended questions of this sort go beyond what the sites Q&A format can properly support.  Feel free to [edit] your question and narrow it down to a specific issue that you are experiencing, and the community should be able to help with answering that.

Comment: @GlenH7 Ok, thanks for your Answers, ill learn about it, and when i have a more specivic problem, ill ask here again. :)

Comment: idkfa's reference is good. | Energy in water is mass flow per second x head drop. 50% out is good. More if careful eg EXAMPLE ONLY: 10 litres/second x 1.5 metre head.
Power = litres/second  x head x 10 x 50% = 10 x 1.5 x 10 x 0.5 = 75 Watts.  Treadmill motors often good - but gearing or chain and sprockets or belts and pulleys usually needed. | Washing machine **direct drive** "brushless DC" motors excellent  eg NZ (now Haier) Fisher & Paykel smart drive motors - good for 100's of watts and lowish speed operation.. Refine question and get it reopened. Much can be said :-)